# I need two separate buttons, one with three options, one with two, that will select one of six webpages

Tags: javascript, forms, button, submit

I have been stuck for months researching and watching videos for what I assumed would be easy. Basically, (and this is just an example to simplify) I have two buttons. Let's say the first is the colors red, white, and blue. The second is dog and cat. So I need all blue cats to go to a registration page for blue cats and red dogs to go to the red dog registration page and so on for each of the six possibilities.  Is this possible and how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use two select tags (something like)

```
<select id='color'>
  <option value='red'>red</option>
  <option value='green'>green</option>
  <option value='blue'>blue</option>
</select>
<select id='animal'>
  <option value='dog'>Dog</option>
  <option value='cat'>Cat</option>
</select>
<button value='Go To Page' onclick='javascript:Goto()'></button>

function Goto()
{
  var color = document.getElementById( 'color' ).value;
  var animal = document.getElementById( 'animal' ).value;
}
```

Comment: OK so I was onto the right track, but I am still confused. I had something like<select id='color'>
  <option value='1'>red</option>
  <option value='2'>green</option>
  <option value='3'>blue</option>
</select>
<select id='animal'>
  <option value='1'>Dog</option>
  <option value='2'>Cat</option>
</select>
All the rest I was way off target.  I was trying to use the function If and if else with conditional statements leading to the page.  What would I have to name the registration page to make your example work?

Comment: @MatthewClegg you should pass this information as parameters to a single registration page like abc.com/register?color=red&animal=cat